# How convert a string into a number javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is 11.786.775,13 and I need to convert into a number, but if I use parseInt return 11, and if I use parseFloat return 11.786, I need the 11.786.775,13 but as a number.
Here my code:

```
let x = number.toLocaleString('pt-br', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
```

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this.

Comment: Remove the `.` characters and replace `,` with `.`, then call `parseFloat()`.

Comment: But I need the number in that way, if I remove the dot it will change

Comment: Why are you parsing localised numbers? Formatting is only for human consumption, the underlying data should always be in formats the system can use.

Answer (score 0):

replace the dots with an empty string and the comma with a dot and then use parseFloat

```
const cleanStrNumber = x.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',','.');
const num = parseFloat(cleanStrNumber, 10);
```

Comment: what if the thousands separator is a comma instead of a dot?

Comment: replace with regex will replace all instances. the second one without the regex will only replace the one instance

Comment: wait, you are asking about a different problem. The format in question is 11.786.775,13
if the formant is 11.786,775,13 you will have to do some more work removing the last two digits and comma first

Comment: `x.replace(/./g, '')` results in an empty string ... you do know what `.` does in regex

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```js
let x = '11.786.775,13';
x = parseFloat(x.split('.').join('').replace(',','.'));
console.log(typeof x, x);
```

for x equals '11.786.775,13' or '175,13' slower (3%) than `.replace(/\./g, '')`;
but for x = '9.9.9.9.9.9.9.9.9.9.9.9.11.786.775,13', replace is slower than split-join construction

if you have small numbers(less 4 points), it is better to choose @tomer-almog design(replace).

Comment: ECMAScript can't accurately handle "99999999999911786775" anyway. ;-) 3% of a few nanoseconds is a very short time…

Comment: @RobG how do you know that the creator(or any man from the future...) of the question does not have 9999 numbers, in 9999 cycles? *Rhetorical question*

Comment: And then they decide to use `.toLocaleString('pt-br', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, style: 'currency', currency: ...})` and it will suddenly break.

Comment: I just saying: he should be free and choose what suits him.. (same thing with people from the future\google)